# how to turn amount*(1+percent)/10 into a mongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In aggregate I have reached this point:

```
amount: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$amount", {$add: ["$percent", 1]}]  }  }  } }]);
```

When I want to use `$divide` it gives me the error of `unknown group operator '$divide'"`. How to divide this by 10?

**EDIT:**

```
db.junk.aggregate([{  $project: {  _id: 0,  cart_closed: 1,  amount: 1,  
percent: 1, shop_id: 1  } }, {  $group: {  
_id: {  cart_closed: {  month: {  $month: "$cart_closed"  },  year: {   
$year: "$cart_closed"  }  }, shop_id: "$shop_id"  },  amount: { $sum: {   
$multiply: ["$amount", {$add: ["$percent", 1]}]  }  }  } }]);
```

Actually I don't `group by` using that arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting errors then you are calling the method in the wrong place. Anything under `$group` must either be the grouping `_id` or an accumulator function, such as `$sum`:

Presuming you have documents like this:

```js
{ "amount": 100, "percent": 10 },
{ "amount": 20, "percent": 33 }
```

Then you just do something like this:

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "amount": { "$sum": {
            "$multiply": [
                "$amount",
                { "$divide": [ "$percent", 100 ] },
            ]
        }}
    }}
])
```

Or for documents like this:

```js
{ "amount": 100, "percent": .10 },
{ "amount": 20, "percent": .33 }
```

Then it's just a simple `$multiply`:

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "amount": { "$sum": {
            "$multiply": [
                "$amount",
                "$percent"
            ]
        }}
    }}
])
```

Both give the expected result:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "amount" : 16.6 }
```

Otherise if the fields are not present then just fill in the constant values you want.

Just a matter of calling everything in the accumulator. If you wanted to "divide after" the sum, then you `$project` after the `$group` stage.

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "amount": { "$sum": "$amount" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "amount": { "$multiply": [ "$amount", .70 ] }
    }}
])
```

If you are not even grouping at all then just use the math on the field:

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "amount": {
            "$multiply": [
                "$amount",
                "$percent"
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

To discount say by 5% where stored like this:

```js
{ "amount": 100, "percent": .05 }
```

Then you do:

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "amount": {
            "$multiply": [
                "$amount",
                { "$subtract": [ 1, "$percent" ] }
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bc9d29408c74e7d57c0176"), "amount" : 95 }
```

Being 5% ( 5 ) lower than the original amount.

Your formula returns a different result. Order the operations to BODMAS:

```js
db.junk.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "amount": {
            "$divide": [
                { "$multiply": [
                    "$amount",
                    { "$add": [ 1, "$percent" ] }
                ]},
                10
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Which is:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55bc9d29408c74e7d57c0176"), "amount" : 10.5 }
```

Comment: tnx, could you see the `EDIT` part plz?

Comment: @phpGeek Already did. All you need is `$multiply`. Or replace your `$sum` with `$add` since `$sum` is a grouping accumulator. But really you just need `$multiply`

Comment: ok then where is your /10 (division by 10). it is always 10:  12*(1+0.08)/10...

And by the way I dont grouping it at all. I just group by `date` & `shop_id`

Comment: When I dont use amount in group, and just use it in `$project` it is not shown in output.

Comment: @phpGeek I'ts just moving operators. I think you are trying to discount. See the example at the end.

Comment: OK your solution is correct, but why when I put it in $project and not using it in `$group` it is not shown in output?

Comment: @phpGeek Which are you doing, projection or summing the total? The examples here should be quite clear as I show both. Your question "incorrectly" calls `$sum` in a `$project` stage.

Comment: I have grouped by `cart_closed` and `shop_id`. The result I want is to return the below expression based on grouped by records:  `amount*(1+percent)/10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84877/discussion-between-phpgeek-and-blakes-seven).